# Finite double series identity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we see that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^k x_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} x_{ij}$$

if we know that $$\sum_{1\leq j<s\land j\in\mathbb N} x_{ij}=-\sum_{s<j\leq n\land j\in\mathbb N}x_{ij}$$

for all $s\in[0,n]$ and for some numbers $x_{ij}$?

Do we need the above assumption?

Comment: Yes you do. You're summing on a triangle, try to draw it and introduce the sum $S_i = \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij}$

Comment: There is something wrong in the second sum in the first equation; the index of summation is the same in both sums. Perhaps the bottom of the sum should be $k=j$ instead of $j=k$?

Comment: I also just noticed that the indices of $x_{ij}$ do not match the indices of summation: $j,k$. Perhaps it should be $x_{jk}$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the bottom of the second summation on the right of the first equation was intended to be $k=j$ instead of $j=k$ (which seems to be wrong since the same dummy index of summation is used twice), and $x_{ij}$ is really supposed to be $x_{jk}$, then the first equation is true without need of further assumptions. Each side is simply
$$
\sum_{\substack{j,k=1\\j\le k}}^{n-1}x_{jk}
$$